# Accept method to return null - C# .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, decimal

I am building a little application in .NET 4 MVC 2 for the office foosball table. I have this repository with a method summing all the values of one column (decimal) using LINQ to SQL. It looks like this:

```
public decimal GetPlayerRating(int id)
{
    var playerRating = (from r in db.Ratings
                        where r.PlayerID == id
                        select r.Points).Sum();

    return playerRating;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes when it's called it returns `null` because the given player does not have any records in the table. That's fine -- in that case it should just return zero. But I get this error:

> The null value cannot be assigned to a
>   member with type System.Decimal which
>   is a non-nullable value type.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   null value cannot be assigned to a
>   member with type System.Decimal which
>   is a non-nullable value type.

How can I tell my method that it is okay to return a null value? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the null coalese operator

```
return playerRating ?? 0d;
```

That will never return a null.

If you really need to return a nullable valuetype, though try this

```
public decimal? GetPlayerRating(int id)
{ ... }
```

Adding a ? to the end of a value type like double is rewritten into Nullable < type >  (Nullable < double >  here)

When dealing with a nullable value type, be sure to check if it has a value (not null)

```
if ( myNullableType.HasValue ) 
{
    x = myNullableType.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer. It worked! The thing is that I am calling this method from my controller where I am calculating the team rating (two players' respective ratings combined). In retrospect, returning null from my repository might not be the best solution. I think it will be better to return a simple zero. How do I do that when a given player has no records in the table and, thus, his rating sum is null? (I hope that made sense.)

Comment: Np, Your best bet is to file a new SO question for this though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public decimal GetPlayerRating(int id)
{
    return db.Ratings.Where(r=>r.PlayerID == id).Select(r=>r.Points).Sum() ?? 0;

}
```

Or Change your return type to `decimal?` to get it working..